# What insurance company have I subscribed to when I paid health insurance as part of my Skilled Worker Visa to the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, health-insurance, insurance

I have applied for a Skilled Worker Visa to the UK.

As part of it, I paid years' of health insurance.

Who is my insurance company now? I need this to report to my home health insurance company.

Unfortunately my employer's Human Resources could not answer this question.

Comment: Its not a health insurance company, its the NHS (National Health Service).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven’t subscribed to an insurance company. That’s not how UK immigration’s approach to healthcare works.

You paid an immigration health surcharge (IHS) that entitles you to use the National Health Service (NHS) if your visa application is successful. https://www.gov.uk/healthcare-immigration-application/who-needs-pay